# I want to divide query output into two columns in Oracle

Tags: sql, csv, oracle11g

First of all,
I feel sorry because of my poor English
but I need your help.

My question is:

I want to divide query output into two columns in oracle and save as it a .csv file

My query is

```
spool test.csv; 
select record_id||'|'||message_text 
from x$dbgalertext; 
spool off
```

What I want is:

```
column1    column2
recordid | message_text
1        |     values~~
2        |     values~~~
```

But what I get is

```
column1
recordid
ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ
1
ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ
messagetext
ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ
values....
```

The weird thing is...
when the values are short like

```
(1,'aaa')
(2,'bbb')
```

It divides as expected.

Answer (score 0):

SQL*PLUS is doing its line-length management "magic." You may wish to try this query:

```
 select record_id || '|' || SUBSTR(message_text, 50) message_text
from x$dbgalertext;
```

If that doesn't work try using `SET LINESIZE 80` or some such command right after your SPOOL command.